# Combine single characters with single spaces between them together

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to combine together single characters which have a single space between them.

For example:

```
 a b c       -->   abc         [all combined together]
 ab c d ef   -->   ab cd ef    [just combine the middle 'c d'
 foo bar    -->   foo bar    [nothing between consecutive words]
```

I can capture this term using the regex `re.findall(r'(([A-z] ){2,})' object)`.   However, I'm not sure how to set up the replace part.

The only way i can think of is in three stages:

1. Search for the term with a `re.findall()` function.
2. Combine the captured terms together.
3. Then to do a replacement with a `re.sub()`.

This however seems a bit messy, and as I'm using over many 10's millions of record, would prefer to just do as a single regex statement, if that is possible.

Comment: So that is: delete the space between two characters(like `f b`). But save the space between two words(like `foo bar`). Right?

Comment: @KevinGuan - yes, it is just between single characters [basically, I'm looking to combine acronyms together ... converting for example `a k a` into `aka`]

Comment: Okay, maybe add these explanations to your question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for two single-letter words, the second one as a lookahead so that it can be examined next:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\b(\w) (?=\w\b)", r"\1", "ab c d e and f")
'ab cde and f'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with regex:

```
(?<=\b\w)\s(?=\w\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cY8tZ2/3)

and then replece matched spaces with nothing.